# PL/SQL: best way to count elements in an array?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Given this:

```
DECLARE
  TYPE T_ARRAY IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(2000) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
  MY_ARRAY T_ARRAY;
  V_COUNT INTEGER;
```

I would like to do:

```
BEGIN
  -- ... some code filling the MY_ARRAY array

  -- obviously COUNT_ELEMENTS() does not exists, this is what I'm looking for :-)
  V_COUNT := COUNT_ELEMENTS(MY_ARRAY);

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('My array containts ' || V_COUNT || ' elements.');
END;
```

Is there something better than creating a procedure doing a basic loop incrementing a counter? Maybe a PL/SQL native function already does this `COUNT_ELEMENTS()`?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I think this is what you're after:

```
V_COUNT := MY_ARRAY.COUNT;
```

Answer (score 8):

Fortunately, I found in the existing PL/SQL code I have to maintain, a working "native" behavior:

```
V_COUNT := MY_ARRAY.COUNT;
```

should do the trick.

This one is very hard to find with Google, since "count" is more frequently referring to the `SELECT COUNT(...)` which can be found in SQL queries...

Comment: And [here's](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/composites.htm#CIHGJCHF) a link to the docs :-)

Answer (score 7):

In case of a Nested-Table (i.e. without `INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER`) you can also use [CARDINALITY](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions015.htm#SQLRF06305)

```
V_COUNT := CARDINALITY(MY_ARRAY);
```

Important difference: In case of Nested-Table which is NULL, `COUNT` raises an exception, `CARDINALITY` returns NULL.

Answer (score 2):

```
declare
   type array_t is varray(10) of number(10);
   array array_t := array_t(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
c number(10):=0;
b number(10):=0;
begin<<outer>>
   for i in 1..array.count loop
    if( mod(i,2)=0)
then
 c:=c+i;
end if;
   end loop;
dbms_output.put_line(c);
begin
    for i in 1..array.count loop
 if( mod(i,2)<>0)
then
 b:=b+i;
end if;
   end loop;
dbms_output.put_line(b);
end;
end outer;
/
```

Comment: I would use a different variable name than 'array' for the type 'array_t'.  I spent 20 minutes wrestling with my code before I realized 'array' was the variable instead of the type (since I use C, C#, and Java alot).

Answer (score -5):

A basic method is:

```
for i in my_array.first .. my_array.last 
loop 
   v_count:=v_count+1;
end loop;
```

Comment: -1 this will not work for an associative array - see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/composites.htm#CIHECGHG) for why